# System.Commandline implementation of a --[no-]bool-option

Tags: c#, command-line-interface

In many popular CLIs, you can implement a boolean option using `--[no-]flag` -- such that `prog --flag --flag --no-flag` ends up setting `flag=yes`. IOW, 'last one in wins'. See [this option in `git-fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---no-auto-maintenance) as an example.

A naive implementation of this using `System.CommandLine` might look like

```cs
Option<bool?> flag = new(name: "--flag", description: "Set flag to 'yes'");
Option<bool?> noflag = new(name: "--no-flag", description: "Set flag to 'no'");
```

where some logic combines `flag` and `noFlag`, but there doesn't seem to be a way to know which one came last in the arguments without inspecting `System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`. This is also duplicative -- they're prone to get out-of-sync with each other.

Does `System.CommandLine` support this notion natively (where I'm just not finding the docs)? Or is there a reasonable way to get the behavior that's desired without wholly ditching `System.CommandLine` parsing?

Comment: Why do you want to use System.CommandLine (it's still in prerelease). Can't you just parse the command line elements from last to first, have the first occurence set the value and then ignore all the other assignments. Or just parse from front to back and have each occurence overwrite the previous one?

Comment: We're mainly using `System.CommandLine` for its generated help documentation and tab-completion -- not to mention an amount of forced stylistic consistency among the team -- many of which have never even used CLIs before. The draft workaround I've got right now does indeed loop through the command-line args and do as you say, but it's pretty ugly code to have in this context.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with System.CommandLine is that it doesn't consider an order in the options you specify. [See the section in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/commandline/syntax#order-of-options-and-arguments).

So if you define two options ("--flag" and "--no-flag"), and write something like `app.exe --flag --no-flag --flag`, the two "--flag"s will be combined and send to the option handler (which will have a count of two). So all information on which option was specified last is lost.

Consider the following example app using global state to store the result

```cs
using System.CommandLine;

var rootCommand = new RootCommand("Sample app for System.CommandLine");
var result = false;
var optionTrue = new Option<bool?>(name: "--flag", description: "Enable flag", parseArgument: _ => result = true)
{
    AllowMultipleArgumentsPerToken = true,
    Arity = ArgumentArity.Zero,
};
rootCommand.AddGlobalOption(optionTrue);

var optionFalse = new Option<bool?>(name: "--no-flag", description: "Disable flag", parseArgument: _ => result = false)
{
    AllowMultipleArgumentsPerToken = true,
    Arity = ArgumentArity.Zero,
};
rootCommand.AddGlobalOption(optionFalse);
rootCommand.SetHandler(flag => Console.WriteLine(result));
return await rootCommand.InvokeAsync(args);
```

If you call this with the above mentioned command line, you will see each of the handlers only being called once: the "--flag" with count = 2 and the "--no-flag" with count = 1. But you don't care about the count, the order matters. So I don't think `System.CommandLine` offers what you want.

Instead you could just parse the command line parameters manually like I describe in the comments.